# Got error trying to install lablgtk2

Tags: windows, ocaml

I'm trying to install **lablgtk2** for the GUI making on Windows OS.

I've installed OCaml 4.02.3

I follow the instructions in the lablgtk2-install.txt.

And when I run **ocamlc build.ml**, it ends up with the error

```
ocamlc.opt -thread -w s -a -o lablgtk.cma -cclib -llablgtk2 -dllib -llablgtk2 -cclib "-LC:/Gtk/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl" gaux.cmo gpointer.cmo gutf8.cmo glib.cmo gobject.cmo gdkEnums.cmo pangoEnums.cmo gtkEnums.cmo pango.cmo gdk.cmo gdkEvent.cmo gdkKeysyms.cmo gdkPixbuf.cmo gtk.cmo gtkSignal.cmo gtkStock.cmo gtkObject.cmo gtkBaseProps.cmo gtkBinProps.cmo gtkButtonProps.cmo gtkEditProps.cmo gtkListProps.cmo gtkMenuProps.cmo gtkMiscProps.cmo gtkPackProps.cmo gtkRangeProps.cmo gtkTextProps.cmo gtkTreeProps.cmo gtkFileProps.cmo gtkActionProps.cmo gtkBrokenProps.cmo gtkAssistantProps.cmo gtkData.cmo gtkBase.cmo gtkPack.cmo gtkButton.cmo gtkAssistant.cmo gtkMenu.cmo gtkMisc.cmo gtkWindow.cmo gtkList.cmo gtkBin.cmo gtkEdit.cmo gtkRange.cmo gtkText.cmo gtkTree.cmo gtkFile.cmo gtkMain.cmo gtkBroken.cmo gPango.cmo gDraw.cmo gObj.cmo gData.cmo gMain.cmo ogtkBaseProps.cmo ogtkBinProps.cmo ogtkButtonProps.cmo ogtkEditProps.cmo ogtkListProps.cmo ogtkMenuProps.cmo ogtkMiscProps.cmo ogtkPackProps.cmo ogtkRangeProps.cmo ogtkTextProps.cmo ogtkTreeProps.cmo ogtkFileProps.cmo ogtkActionProps.cmo ogtkBrokenProps.cmo ogtkAssistantProps.cmo gContainer.cmo gPack.cmo gButton.cmo gText.cmo gMenu.cmo gMisc.cmo gTree.cmo gList.cmo gFile.cmo gWindow.cmo gAssistant.cmo gBin.cmo gEdit.cmo gRange.cmo gAction.cmo gBroken.cmo gUtil.cmo gToolbox.cmo
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Cannot find file gtkSignal.cmo
Bytecode failed: error 2
```

The lablgtk2 version: 2.18.1-win32

Comment: Have you tried searching for the gtkSignal.cmo file and if it exists adding it to the compiler? You might need to add antoher `-I` flag as well.

Comment: Yes, I have. That is the first thing to be done. But all I've got are gtkSignal.ml, gtkSignal.cmi, and gtkSignal.mli. Might it be possible to produce gtkSignal.cmo "by hands" from source?

Comment: Yes looks like you need to compile it. I think cmo is created with ocamlc

Comment: Ok. I've proceeded to compile to gtkSignal.ml and got a "Segmentaion Fault".

Comment: Would this help in any way? https://www.typerex.org/ocpwin.html